# Probability throw repeatedly at a dart

Tags: probability

I throw darts repeatedly. Assume that on each single throw, my chance of hitting the bulls-eye is $10\%$, independently of all other throws. I decide to throw until I have hit the bulls-eye $3$ times. What is the chance that I throw exactly $30$ times?

$P(\text{throw exactly }30\text{ times})= (1-0.10)^{30}=0.04239=4.239\%$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third success occurs on the $30$th trial if and only if there are **exactly** $2$ successes in the first $29$ trials, and then a success on the $30$th.

If $p$ is the probability of success on any trial, here $0.1$, then the probability of $2$ successes in $29$ trials is $\binom{29}{2}p^2(1-p)^{27}$. Now multiply by $p$.

Comment: You are welcome. The general idea (what is the probability that the $r$-th success occurs on the $n$-th trial) is the same. We get an important distribution called the *negative binomial* distribution.