# Probability - Mathematics

Tags: probability

I throw darts repeatedly. Assume that on each single throw, my chance of hitting the bullseye is 10%, independently of all other throws. I decide to throw until I have hit the bullseye 3 times. What is the chance that I throw exactly 30 times?

Comment: This question has already been [asked and answered today.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376191/probability-throw-repeatedly-at-a-dart)

Comment: Nope, we don't have a problem with MSE being a homework factory.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Negative Binomial distribution. Exactly 30 times mean you have 2 successes in 29 trials, then 30th attempt is success and then you stop. You have all the variables to find this probability. Can you handle from here?